# Style every element of page but one

Tags: css, element, opacity, document-body

I want to style every element of my page except for a particular div. I believe this is done with :not, but I'm not sure. I'm doing this to make the opacity of all elements 0.7, except for a popup.

Comment: Note that if you apply opacity 0.7 to an element, every children gets *semi*-transparent. No need to apply opacity to all of them..

Comment: I apologize - I'm new at programming. What do you mean by semi-transparent? By the way, I am targeting this opacity property to my body, so the opacity affects all elements. With your answer, wouldn't I have to go to each individual element and style it with this opacity property? Isn't there a simple CSS rule to include everything but one element? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What I meant was that opacity is inherited by children elements. So if you apply opacity to everyone it is *added*. Here is an example to explain myself: https://jsfiddle.net/mvtssLn5/

Comment: Awesome answer! I never knew about that property and it's interesting to see a wrapping effect with style. However, I found this code worked better for me. How do I make this code the accepted answer? div:not(.block_opacity) {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my alternative sugestion: a layer with opacity in front of the web, but behind the overlay.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/j1jodsej/

HTML

```
<div id="overlaybg"></div>
<div id="overlay">
    I'm the overlay
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
    text-align: justify;
}
#overlaybg {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 30px;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Also a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a id/class like `no-opacity` and then in css `opacity: 1 !important;`

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lez6kkgw/1/